# Show message when a specific Group contains no items in a Grouped ListView

Tags: wpf, xaml

In UI only Accounting, Economics, Finance group section is seen as there are items in those group. How to show Marketing group with message "No employs on Marketing". Want to show the message only from marketing and not Management Group Section if its empty.

The message will only appear if there are no employees in the Marketing department. If there are employees in the Marketing department, the message will be hidden.

[image]

XAML CODE:

```
    <Grid>
        <Grid.Resources>
            <CollectionViewSource Source="{Binding Path=items}"
                                          x:Key="GroupedItems">
                <CollectionViewSource.GroupDescriptions>
                    <PropertyGroupDescription PropertyName="dept" />
                </CollectionViewSource.GroupDescriptions>
            </CollectionViewSource>
        </Grid.Resources>
        <ListView Name="lvEmps" ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource GroupedItems}}">
            <ListView.View>
                <GridView>
                    <GridViewColumn Header="Name" Width="150" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Name}" />
                    <GridViewColumn Header="Age" Width="50" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Age}" />
                    <GridViewColumn Header="Email" Width="150" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Email}" />
                </GridView>
            </ListView.View>
            <ListView.GroupStyle>
                <GroupStyle>
                    <GroupStyle.HeaderTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <TextBlock FontWeight="Bold" FontSize="14" Text="{Binding Name}"/>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </GroupStyle.HeaderTemplate>
                </GroupStyle>
            </ListView.GroupStyle>
        </ListView>
    </Grid>
```

c# code:

```
    public class Employee
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public int Age { get; set; }
        public string Email { get; set; }
        public Department dept { get; set; }
    }

    public enum Department
    {
        Accounting,Economics, Finance,Management,Marketing
    }
```